# PHP - MySQL request - No data found

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, select

I have a problem with my php file. I want to create a JSON result for the newest values of my weather station. If i run the file, it says that there is no data available.
But if i execute the same request at phpmyadmin, it shows me the newest data. can someone help me:

Here is the php file:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

include ("dbData.php");

$query = "
SELECT datumzeit
     , tempInnen
     , tempAussen
     , feuchteInnen
     , feuchteAussen
     , luftdruck 
  FROM wetterdaten
 ORDER 
    BY datumzeit DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
";

$q_data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($q_data) > 0) 
{
  $r_data = mysql_fetch_array($q_data);
  $DATUM  = $r_data['datumzeit'];
  $tempInnen  = number_format($r_data['tempInnen'], 2, '.', '');
  $tempAussen  = number_format($r_data['tempAussen'], 2, '.', '');
  $feuchteInnen  = number_format($r_data['feuchteInnen'], 2, '.', '');
  $feuchteAussen  = number_format($r_data['feuchteAussen'], 2, '.', '');
  $luftdruck  = number_format($r_data['luftdruck'], 2, '.', ''); 
}
else
{
$E = 1;
$M = "Do Data available.";
}
    if(!isset($E))
    {
?>
{
  "wetterstation": [{
    "TempInnen": "<?php echo $tempInnen;?>",
    "TempAussen": "<?php echo $tempAussen;?>",
    "feuchteInnen": "<?php echo $feuchteInnen;?>",
    "feuchteAussen": "<?php echo $feuchteAussen;?>",
    "luftdruck": "<?php echo $luftdruck;?>"
  ]}
}
<?php
}
    else
    {
      echo $M;
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

Solved:

After i changed:

```
$q_data = mysql_query("SELECT datumzeit, tempInnen, tempAussen, feuchteInnen,feuchteAussen,luftdruck FROM wetterdaten ORDER BY datumzeit DESC LIMIT 1;")or die mysql:error());
```

to:

```
 $query = "
SELECT datumzeit
     , tempInnen
     , tempAussen
     , feuchteInnen
     , feuchteAussen
     , luftdruck 
  FROM wetterdaten
 ORDER 
    BY datumzeit DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
";

$q_data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I guess it shouldn't be a semicolon in the end of your query - ` ...LIMIT 1;` , just `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: You should not generate your json manually, just dump everything in an array and use `echo json_encode($your_array)`.

Comment: it deleted the ORDERED BY while copy the code in this thread

Comment: Please do not use deprecated functions (mysql_)

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging, like some `var_dump()`'s at the different stages of the relevant variables.

Comment: it works now ! The problem was how i wrote the $q_data = ... line. @Strawberry edited my post, than i changed my php file like he edited for me. now it works fine

Comment: i didn't make any functional change to your code - only an aesthetic one!

Comment: yes i know, but it works now! i didn't change something.. i just copied your edit and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

first remove last ; from query and use mysql_fetch_object for limit 1
try like this(not tested):

```
$q_data  = mysql_query("SELECT datumzeit, tempInnen, tempAussen, feuchteInnen,  feuchteAussen, luftdruck FROM wetterdaten  LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($q_data) > 0) 
{
  $r_data = mysql_fetch_object($q_data);
  $DATUM  = $r_data->datumzeit;
  $tempInnen  = number_format($r_data->tempInnen, 2, '.', '');
  $tempAussen  = number_format($r_data->tempAussen, 2, '.', '');
  $feuchteInnen  = number_format($r_data->feuchteInnen, 2, '.', '');
  $feuchteAussen  = number_format($r_data->feuchteAussen, 2, '.', '');
  $luftdruck  = number_format($r_data->luftdruck, 2, '.', ''); 
}
```

Comment: No. Keep the last ';'. It's not strictly necessary, but it's easier to debug with it there, and PHP doesn't care either way.

Comment: If the last ';' is the mysql query one, recently i also found out that the query string from mysql_query should not end in semicolon. ( see http://www.php.net/mysql_query ) ... don't know the reason though...

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified if you just need one row, this way you can detect faster what's wrong.

[mysql_query page](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) : *The query string should not end with a semicolon.*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include ("dbData.php");

$query = "SELECT datumzeit, tempInnen, tempAussen, feuchteInnen,  feuchteAussen, luftdruck FROM wetterdaten  LIMIT 1";
$q_data  = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ($r_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_data)) {
    //you could use json_encode($r_data) here if not for number_format and wetterstation key
    ?>
    {
    "wetterstation": [{
    "TempInnen": "<?php echo number_format($r_data['tempInnen'], 2, '.', '');?>",
    "TempAussen": "<?php echo number_format($r_data['tempAussen'], 2, '.', '');?>",
    "feuchteInnen": "<?php echo number_format($r_data['feuchteInnen'], 2, '.', '');?>",
    "feuchteAussen": "<?php number_format($r_data['feuchteAussen'], 2, '.', ''); ?>",
    "luftdruck": "<?php echo number_format($r_data['luftdruck'], 2, '.', '');?>"
    ]}
    }
<?php
}else{
    ?> Do Data available. <?
}
```